# Sitecore 9 Experience Profile An Error has occurred

Tags: experience-profile

When I open the `Experience Profile` tab on my `Sitecore 9` dashboard, I get an error:

[image: An error has occured! image]

So naturally, I checked the logs and got the following error and stack trace:

```
>  24872 15:35:09 ERROR [Sitecore Services]: HTTP GET URL
> http://demo.site/sitecore/api/ao/v1/contacts/search?&pageSize=20&pageNumber=1&sort=visitCount
> desc&match=asdfasdsaf&searchfromdatefilter=01%2F06%2F2017&searchtodatefilter=09%2F11%2F2017&searchchannelfilters={"name":"CHANNEL_FILTERS"%2C"SearchItems":[{"ItemId":"F575D5E6-74DE-49B6-A866-E2256D213D83"}]}&searchcampaignfilters=null&searchoutcomefilters={"name":"OUTCOME_FILTERS"%2C"SearchItems":[{"ItemId":"062A1E69-0BF6-4D6D-AC4F-C11D0F7DC1E1"}]}&searchgoalfilters={"name":"GOAL_FILTERS"%2C"SearchItems":[{"ItemId":"0CB97A9F-CAFB-42A0-8BE1-89AB9AE32BD9"}]}&searchprofilefilters=null&searchdevicefilters=null
> 

> Exception System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at
> Sitecore.Cintel.Endpoint.Plumbing.NegotiateLanguageFilter.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext
> actionExecutedContext)    at
> System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecutedAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext
> actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
>     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext()
>     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
>     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
>     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext()
>     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
>     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
>     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext()
>     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()
>     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()
>     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()
>     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()
```

I found this post:
https://www.brimit.com/blog/sitecore-9-experience-profile-workaround

But I believe, that is a different problem. Can anyone help me finding out, what is causing the error? I'm at a loss.

**EDIT 1:**

I decided to extend my post with some more info about my project:
I'm adding Contacts and Interactions to xConnect from a .NET Core application.
I have got a custom xConnect model.

**EDIT 2:**

Request header was requested so here it is:

```
GET /sitecore/api/ao/v1/contacts/search?&pageSize=20&pageNumber=%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B1&sort=visitCount%20%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bdesc&match=*&searchf%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bromdatefilter=08%2F1%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B0%2F2017&searchtodat%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Befilter=09%2F11%2F20%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B17&searchchannelfilt%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bers=null&searchcampa%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bignfilters=null&sear%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bchoutcomefilters=nul%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bl&searchgoalfilters=%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bnull&searchprofilefi%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Blters=null&searchdev%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bicefilters=null HTTP/1.1
Host: demo.site
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cookie: scContentEditorFoldersWidth=350; ASP.NET_SessionId=pwjpqa0edoppcgatss1bvmdi; shell#lang=en; __RequestVerificationToken=HnLdm_Now0Drb1P5cSUL4SldKgBBA7IjNyniEEizH-ZtceXy5dvvbheEeHV0bZowutgHlB7m_oLzLC-RTjjCWlkUEX8KrMsda_mhK2igSik1; __CSRFCOOKIE=4476f530-f75a-4ba8-bed4-4909607be60f; sc_fv=0.0.0; login#lang=en; sc_rte_shuser=2E9DAC23EC129E0F1B7D1B113712FEFCE23CBE8A1E770E0CF3198B88833E18BA7C98E4E51FF67BF4E76119BADC0419DADF48CD386DEE7192704505175E22A2D2D7412CAE567BC2973BDB9A01D67759A082039AB688898F348B09F7853A693D97352F49AEC76BED14B076F91D7AB7C530; website#sc_date=; sc_pview_shuser=209481495D3A610022B06B4C4B369240D448EF3D0C84D082172E3AA65E9A1493BFE98AC1EAB9EF217CC86968707DD6C990EE5EFE808491F4DCE4B595D0E5CF1E2F315AF0286F6DB76B339FED839915DD2C44C6A8927590237BB1DDA2331F1AF8D4E319630FE20926682BA578E751D27E; website#sc_mode=preview; website#lang=en; shell#sc_mode=; SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE=ea13502c80f84227909a2b77bcce2d77|True; sitecore_userticket=4904DD0629ED4175B5F029EC5EB226C5; .ASPXAUTH=144264DA69EA8BFF543760CDF27F5B92CDE96DEA99AD0CD9C45D05717DBC593965F5EB6B614A7F76A2BCBA6C8F6A5C0AEE8203187C7435289A5F3EABA675254DF053FEC600F32C07C03457A129777B5862A27C64780CD1A3F819CAA104EEF7F75FC5EF4483FC15AE9CA26695E64A29E9
```

I was fairly hesitant to post my code for creating the Contact and Interaction because I have it very split up throughout my application.
I tried adding the `IpInfo` and `WebVisit` Facets but without luck so here we go:

**Adding a Contact:**

```
    public async Task<Contact> AddContact(string email)
    {
        var cfg = await _xconnect.InitializeXConnect();
        using (var client = new XConnectClient(cfg))
        {
            try
            {
                var contact = new Contact(
                           new ContactIdentifier("email", email, ContactIdentifierType.Known)
                           );
                client.AddContact(contact);
                await client.SubmitAsync();
                return contact;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Adding an interaction:**

```
public async Task<bool> SendInteraction(Interaction i, StoreInfo storeInfo, ProfileScores profileScore, Contact contact)
    {
        var cfg = await _xconnect.InitializeXConnect();
        using (var client = new XConnectClient(cfg))
        {
            try
            {
                client.SetFacet(i, StoreInfo.DefaultFacetKey, storeInfo);
                client.SetFacet(i, ProfileScores.DefaultFacetKey, profileScore);
                FillRequiredFacets(client, i, contact);
                client.AddInteraction(i);
                await client.SubmitAsync();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void FillRequiredFacets(XConnectClient client, Interaction interaction, Contact existingContact)
    {
        //Add Device profile
        DeviceProfile newDeviceProfile = new DeviceProfile(Guid.NewGuid());
        newDeviceProfile.LastKnownContact = existingContact;
        client.AddDeviceProfile(newDeviceProfile);
        interaction.DeviceProfile = newDeviceProfile;

        //Add fake Ip info
        IpInfo fakeIpInfo = new IpInfo("127.0.0.1");
        fakeIpInfo.BusinessName = "Home";
        client.SetFacet<IpInfo>(interaction, IpInfo.DefaultFacetKey, fakeIpInfo);

        //Add fake webvisit
        WebVisit fakeWebVisit = new WebVisit();
        fakeWebVisit.SiteName = "Offline";
        client.SetFacet<WebVisit>(interaction, WebVisit.DefaultFacetKey, fakeWebVisit);
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69921/discussion-on-question-by-mark-de-jong-sitecore-9-experience-profile-an-error-ha).

Comment: Experience Profile uses xConnect to search for contacts. A couple of things to check: 1. xConnect logs \App_Data\logs folder. 2. Ensure that Solr's endpoing is reachable (enpoint is configured in \App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config solrCore).

Comment: my solr endpoint is not reachable, i'll go have a look why!

Comment: the connectionstring had the following link: https://localhost:8983/solr/Demo_xdb, which was not reachable, however adding a # like so: https://localhost:8983/solr/#/Demo_xdb made it reachable i still get the same error

Comment: @markDEJong, you should change back the Solr string to not contain hash: localhost:8983/solr/Demo_xdb. I only wanted you to verify whether Solr service is started and you confirmed that it is. Any errors in xConnect's log?

Comment: I do get the error: [Error] Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied. but that is not an error that pops up after open the experience profile screen

Comment: Do you get any errors when searching for contacts?

Comment: yes the same as mentioned in the post, the page calls a search for the last month with a * in the search box when opened. If you mean any errors in the xConnect logs after a search then no, i do not

Comment: Sadly i haven't found out why i ran in to this error, some how i did solve it tho...

Comment: step 1 : check this link for creating contact with all the data required.
https://www.brimit.com/blog/sitecore-9-experience-profile-workaround. Step 2: Rebuild the xDB search index. Easiest way to do that is via CMD Windows.
Navigate to the folder XCONNECT_ROOT_FOLDER \App_data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker
Run XConnectSearchIndexer.exe as Administrator.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue as well.  For me, it was the Newtonsoft.Json assembly.  I had the latest one in my bin since I normally like to use the latest ((thru NuGet).  Anyway, after some several trial and error, the Newtonsoft.Json was culprit.  It needs to be the v9.0.1.  The one that came with SC9.  After replacing it, the error went away.  Now, I'm not sure if your contacts will show up but that may be a different issue.

As LonghornTaco said above, errors may not be getting trapped smoothly.  Also, there may be some bugs still.  For instance, the particular error you have above with NegotiateLanguageFilter.  It's an attribute that adds Language in the response header of the controller.  Because of this, it's possible that the HttpContent may be null.  That's not being checked when the language is being set.

Comment: I already tried re-installing the entire solution so i don't  think it is the Newtonsoft.Json assembly, i checked the version and it should be right..
Guess i'll try to find out why the HttpContent is null.

Comment: It may be time for you to open a ticket with support.

Comment: I assume that a clean SC9 shows the Experience Profile just fine, correct?  If the Newtonsoft.Json is not the culprit, see if it's one of your other assemblies.

Comment: i some how got rid of the error and am seeing a couple of unknown contacts, i was however expecting a couple contacts with names, back to investigating

Comment: identifies are not shown in that list, after filling the name and email facet the list made more sence.

Comment: I'm glad it's working. So, what did you think the initial problem was and what solved it?  Just making sure.

Comment: Can you explain how did you solve the issue? I think i'm running in the same error as you.

Comment: @FabioCarello Is yours on the list of contacts?  Or, within a contact?  My answer was take a look at the version of the Newtonsoft.Json assembly.  You can also check if the connection to xConnect is working.

Answer (score 3):

I have checked the xConnect logs `\App_Data\logs` folder to check for the errors and found out that there is an error in accessing the SSL certificates.

The error says `The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.`
I was able to fix it by running the script available at https://gist.github.com/jermdavis/8d8a79f680505f1074153f02f70b9105

I ran the part of the script which is responsible for setting up SSL for Solr.

Answer (score 2):

Any chance you could post the code you're using to create the `Contact` and `Interaction`?  When creating the interaction manually, outside of a Sitecore context (like in your .NET core app), there are a few bits you need to construct that you may not realize.  For instance, if this is an online interaction, you need to specify data for the `IpInfo` facet.  There were two or three objects, when I was creating my xConnect console app, that I did not know to create until I started digging.

Whenever you're viewing the xProfile for a user, a series of pipelines are kicked off.  Take the `Sitecore.Cintel.Reporting.ReportingServerDatasource.Visits.GetVisitsWithLocations` processor for example.  In the `FillTableWithRow` method, they are expecting a non-null `IpInfo` object with valid data:

```
    public class GetVisitsWithLocations : ReportProcessorBase
    {
        private void FillTableWithRow(DataTable rawTable, Sitecore.XConnect.Interaction curInteraction, int index = 1)
        {
            WebVisit webVisit = curInteraction.WebVisit();
            IpInfo ipInfo = curInteraction.IpInfo();
            ...
            DataRow row = rawTable.NewRow();
            ...
            row["DeviceId"] = (object) curInteraction.DeviceProfile.Id;
            ...
            row["Ip"] = (object) ipInfo.IpAddress.ToString();
            ...
            rawTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
```

In my opinion, they are not handling errors well enough, so a call to `ipInfo.IpAddress.ToString();` results in a `NullReferenceException` and will lead to the dashboard error that you're seeing.

So, as I mentioned earlier, it would be helpful to see the code you're using to actually create the `Contact` and populate the `Interaction` data.

Comment: I'm not near my pc for the next 2 days so i can't share the code i've used for now. I do think i do not have to fill all of these fields tho, i've followed the link down here to work around that problem: https://www.brimit.com/blog/sitecore-9-experience-profile-workaround

Comment: One more reason i do not think this is the cause of this error is because i have set the search filter to today (so there should be no results) and i get the same error

Comment: If you use chrome, open the developer tools (`F12`) and click the `Network` tab, then reload the page. See which calls are throwing the errors.

Comment: the search call is throwing the error, it returns the error and stacktrace mentioned in my post

Comment: Is there any specific information from that call that you would like to see?

Comment: I decided to fill the IpInfo Facet, the WebVisit Facet and the DeviceProfile, I have emptied my shard databases and i have sent another Interaction. I still get the same error

Answer (score 2):

If you are using profiles (Profile cards and pattern cards), then this error is occurring because you have not deployed the profiles that you had created **under /sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Profiles/**

You should **deploy those profiles** to the web database, to solve this error. Click on the profile you have created -> Click the Review tab found in the Sitecore ribbon menu area  -> Under Workflow Chunk/Section, Click on the **Deploy** button

**NOTE :** Publishing the site or item does not automatically deploy profiles you have created. You must do this manually.

**This was also the solution for the below error in Sitecore Experience Analytics/ Experience Profile** that I faced while using profile cards and pattern cards:

> The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is
>   not present.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this also and unable to create a contact as well on List Manager and I've managed to fix this doing the things below.

1. Restart (SiteName).xconnect Site in IIS.
2. Stop Solr.
3. Delete the core `sitecore_xdb` in the file system of Solr.
4. Add the core `sitecore_xdb` folder again with the default items in /conf and data in the file system.
5. Add the core again on the https://localhost:8983/solr/#/~cores/ and
   map the created folder.
6. Start Solr.
7. Run `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\(SiteName).xconnect\App_data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\XConnectSearchIndexer.exe`

Thanks to this post which I also refer. https://blog.wesleylomax.co.uk/2017/11/01/solrcore-initialization-failures-xconnect-sitecore-9/

Answer (score 1):

You'll get that exception if an exception was thrown in an action of a controller that has the `NegotiateLanguageFilter` attribute applied to it.

There's not much code in that ActionFilter, but some does depend on `actionExecutedContext.Response` which will (may?) be null if an exception is thrown previously in a controller.

Where I was getting this was in Sitecore.Cintel.Endpoint.ContactController.Search.  If you dig down in this method, it eventually creates an XConnect client via the `xconnect/clientconfig` config section

Suggestions from how I got to the root of why my instance was failing:

- Check Sitecore logs.  If you can see another thrown exception being logged in there, fix it and see if the exception in the ActionFilter goes away.
- Check the logs of supporting services (xconnect collection, xconnect search...).  If there's any exception in there, fix and try again.
- If you still can't figure out what's going on, start breaking stuff and try to get another exception to occur.  Break your xconnect connection string(s) and see if you get a new exception in your Sitecore log.  That'll at least tell you it attempted and failed to contact xconnect where it was succeeding earlier

My solution was the second bullet.  My CM was configured to point to the xconnect collection website instead of the xconnect search website.

**The fix** was changing this: `<add name="xconnect.collection" connectionString="https://collection.inside.test" />`

to this: `<add name="xconnect.collection" connectionString="https://search.inside.test" />`

This manifested itself in the xcollect collection log like this:

> 2020-01-06 22:01:11.583 -08:00 [Error] ["XdbContextLoggingPlugin"] XdbContext Batch Execution Exception
>   System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
>      at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.IndexReaderDisabled.SearchContacts(SearchQuery searchQuery)
>      at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Repository.d__11.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.RepositoryCountersDecorator.<SearchContacts>d__8.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>      at Sitecore.XConnect.Service.RepositorySearchInvoker.d__7.MoveNext()
>   2020-01-06 22:03:38.876 -08:00 [Error] Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.XdbSearchOperation`1[Sitecore.XConnect.Contact]: System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
>      at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.IndexReaderDisabled.SearchContacts(SearchQuery searchQuery)
>      at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Repository.<SearchContacts>d__11.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.RepositoryCountersDecorator.d__8.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>      at Sitecore.XConnect.Service.RepositorySearchInvoker.d__7.MoveNext()

Answer (score 0):

I found this blog useful. My issue got resolved because of the second point.

http://www.coldat.com/2019/01/31/sitecore-9-experience-profile-contacts-error/

Ensure SOLR path connection strings are formed correctly. For example,  they should not have hashes in:

**Correct:**

https://localsolr:8984/solr/xp_xdb” />

**Wrong:**

https://localsolr:8984/solr/#/xp_xdb” />

XConnect\App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config
XConnect\App_Data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\App_config\ConnectionStrings.config

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below things.

1- Check the connection string on CM Server and check "xconnect.collection.certificate" has the same thumbprint that you have for Xconnect certificate on Xconnect Server.

2- Make sure your server certificate (SSL) for XConnect is valid and can be validated from CM Server.

3- run MMC and check that certificate is exist in your local machine

4- And In MMC>localmachine> edit the permission for certificate and give full control to account(Network Service/something else) in which application is running.

Let me know if you are facing any issue for the above points

Thanks

I have given the same solution for below question-
[Sitecore XP 9.1.1 certificates error](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/19037/sitecore-xp-9-1-1-certificates-error/19048#19048)