# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in Experience Profile (SC9 & SQL xDB)

Tags: xdb, sitecore-api, xconnect

I’ve successfully installed SC9 and have been able to push contacts into xDB via xConnect without any problems. I can see the contacts in the SQL database and that bit is working fine.

Something like the below is working fine:

http://localhost/sitecore/api/ao/v1/contacts/CE378614-3A11-0000-0000-052E03CA0043

[image]

The issue is, when i am loading the Experience Profile, i am encountered with below exception. I've applied the patch Sitecore.Support.192372 but that didn't resolve the issue.

> 8644 15:06:20 ERROR [Sitecore Services]: HTTP GET URL
>   http://localhost/sitecore/api/ao/v1/contacts/search?&pageSize=20&pageNumber=1&sort=visitCount
>   desc&match=*&searchfromdatefilter=18%2F11%2F2017&searchtodatefilter=18%2F01%2F2018&searchchannelfilters=null&searchcampaignfilters=null&searchoutcomefilters=null&searchgoalfilters=null&searchprofilefilters=null&searchdevicefilters=null
>
> Exception System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to
>   an instance of an object.    at
>   Sitecore.Cintel.Endpoint.Plumbing.NegotiateLanguageFilter.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext
>   actionExecutedContext)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecutedAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext
>   actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

[image]

[image]

I am new to the Sitecore and just wonder, if someone could give me a quick pointer to what I’ve done wrong?

Comment: It's Sitecore 9.0.0 rev 171002.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial release of Sitecore 9 (rev 171002) does not support non-web interactions, as specified in [this post](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8907/sitecore-9-experience-profile-an-error-has-occured).

Sitecore 9 update-1 has addressed this issue.