# Sitecore XP 9.1.1 certificates error

Tags: xconnect, sitecore-install-framework, certificate

I get the following error from my CD Server(serverB)

```
The certificate was not found. Store: My, Location: LocalMachine, FindType: FindByThumbprint, FindValue: """"", InvalidAllowed: False.
```

**Source:** `Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web`

My distributed setup is as follows

I have a 2 server setup

**ServerA -** CM with reporting (installed using XP0 and NOT XP1 script)

**ServerB -** copied the CD website from `serverA` and imported  the XConnect client certificate from `server1`

I have the original CD website on server1 which came with the XP0 setup which is working fine. The error is only on the CD website on `server2`

One more thing the XConnect from serverB to serverA is through an invalid https(read XConnect server certificate) connection!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the below things.

1- Check the connection string on ServerB and check  "xconnect.collection.certificate" has the same thumbprint that you have for Xconnect certificate on ServerA.

2- Make sure your server certificate (SSL) for XConnect is valid and can be validated from ServerB.

3- run MMC and check that certificate is exist in your local machine

4- And In MMC>localmachine> edit the permission for certificate and give full control to account(Network Service/something else) in which application is running.

Let me know if you are facing any issue for the above points

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this way:

**Server-B:**

- import the **XConnect Cert** into **"Cert:\LocalMachine\Root"** --> in order to make a request to XConnect
- import the **XConnect Client Cert** into **"Cert:\LocalMachine\My"** --> in order to pass the security check of XConnect