# Couldn't set avatar facet to contact in experience profile sitecore 9

Tags: sitecore-client, xconnect, contact-facets

I'm using `Sitecore 9.1.1` and I am creating a Contact programmatically and set its facets.

My problem is when I set the `Avatar` facet which is the picture of the contact.

The following code is where I set the `Avatar` facet and I get the Image from media library:

```
private void SetContactAvatar(XConnectClient client, Contact contact, Item account)
    {
        MultilistField mlField = new MultilistField(account.Fields["photos"]);
        Item[] mlFieldItems = mlField.GetItems();
        if (mlFieldItems.Count() != 0)
        {
            MediaItem mediaItem = mlFieldItems[0];
            if (mediaItem != null)
            {
                string profileImageUrl = Sitecore.Globals.ServerUrl + Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(mediaItem);
                System.Net.WebClient objWebClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
                byte[] profileImageBytes = objWebClient.DownloadData(profileImageUrl);

                //Stream stream = mediaItem.GetMediaStream();
                //Byte[] profileImageBytes = new Byte[stream.Length];

                client.SetFacet(contact, Avatar.DefaultFacetKey, new Avatar(mediaItem.MimeType, profileImageBytes)
                {
                    MimeType = mediaItem.MimeType,
                    Picture = profileImageBytes
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

When the contact is created I get a broken Image with the following error:

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException","StackTrace":"   at Sitecore.Cintel.Endpoint.Plumbing.NegotiateLanguageFilter.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecutedAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()"}
```

Can someone advise me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is not related to contact facets. 
You can see how to resolve this error here [Sitecore 9 Experience Profile An Error has occurred](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8907/sitecore-9-experience-profile-an-error-has-occurred).

How to set contact avatar from media item:

This is my working code snippet:

```
public async Task<bool> SetContactAvatar(string source, string identifier, MediaItem mediaItem)
{
    using (XConnectClient client = SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
    {
        try
        {
            var reference = new IdentifiedContactReference(source, identifier);

            var contact = client.GetAsync(
                reference,
                new ContactExpandOptions(CollectionModel.FacetKeys.Avatar)
            );

            Contact existingContact = await contact;

            if (existingContact == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            client.SetFacet(existingContact, Avatar.DefaultFacetKey, new Avatar(mediaItem.MimeType, ReadBytes(mediaItem.GetMediaStream())));
            await client.SubmitAsync();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
}

public static byte[] ReadBytes(Stream input)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        input.CopyTo(ms);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I would only change one thing. If the Avatar exists, you need to update it, not add a new one. If you try and add a new facet model, it would be missing the ConcurrencyToken and throw "Facet already exists" error. Here is an update of your code. https://gist.github.com/dnstommy/65a439899f6f85c4f5d436b6f9fc9f8f